# :.!python3 cannot be used with input()

Tags: command-line

`:.!python3` command is one of my favourites. But it cannot be used with `input()` function. Is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 1):

I actually can't find the duplicate I was looking for, but the solution is to

```
:terminal python3
```

This is slightly different (`:.!` filters the line through the `python3` program, where as this opens a terminal running `python3`), but is fully compatible with code like `input()`. The filtering behavior of `:[range]!` makes it impossible to provide more input via stdin, because the process has already read an EOF from stdin.